# Why does the Pinterest custom share URL not create a rich pin only on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, safari

**Background:** I'm using the custom pin share URL as you can see in the example below.

**Problem:** This share URL works on every single operating system and browser except Safari on iOS. It works in all other browsers on iOS, and it works in Safari on all other operating systems.

**Example Link:** https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://redefiningmom.com/the-real-reason-i-left-corporate-america/&media=http%3A%2F%2Fredefiningmom.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F01%2Freal-reason-i-left-corporate-america-pinterest.jpg&description=After+ten+years%2C+I+quit+my+job+in+Corporate+America.+Find+out+the+real+reason+I+left+Corporate+America+and+how+you+can+too.

**Desired/Usual Behavior:** This link would open a share dialogue leading to the creation of a rich pin with a large image, a description, and a link back to the webpage.

**Undesired Behavior:** Only on Safari on iOS this opens a share dialogue leading to the creation of a non-rich pin with a large image, a description and a link to the image, not the web page.

How do I fix this?

Comment: please add open url code

Comment: I just went to my iPhone (running iOS 9.2.1) and clicked the link embedded above. I got the correct share dialog, and a rich pin was created that links to the web page, not the image. What version of iOS are you running into a problem? Perhaps it was a bug that got fixed later?

Comment: Also are you expecting the user to have the Pinterest app? (which I do, which may be why it worked on my iPhone). Interesting, on my iPad, which also has the app, I just get a blank web page opening.

Answer (score 4):

Using an iPhone 5S with iOS 9.2.1 (the latest), the pages look exactly the same on Chrome and Safari:

[image: Chrome]
[image: Safari]